# Use proof by mathematical induction to prove explicit formula for recursive sequence is correct

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, recursion

Here is the question I am having trouble with.

---

Suppose you have the following recursively defined sequence:

P<sub>1</sub> = 4 
P<sub>k</sub> = P<sub>k-1</sub>+ 4 · 3<sup>k</sup> for all integers k ≥ 2

Suppose you have used the method of iteration to find the following explicit formula:

P<sub>1</sub> = 4 
P<sub>n</sub> = 2 · 3<sup>n+1</sup> - 14 for all integers n ≥ 1

Use proof by mathematical induction to show this is the correct explicit formula.

---

Here is what I have so far:

Base case: n = 1, 4 = 2 · 3<sup>1+1</sup> - 14; 4 = 2 · 9 - 14; 4 = 18 - 14; 4 = 4 ✓

Assume: P<sub>k</sub> = 2 · 3<sup>k+1</sup> - 14 for all integers k >= 1

Now we must show that P<sub>k+1</sub> = 2 · 3<sup>(k+1)+1</sup> - 14

Then we must get P<sub>k+1</sub> = P<sub>k</sub> + 4 · 3<sup>k</sup> to look like what was previously stated. First, let’s substitute in our assumption:

(2 · 3<sup>k+1</sup> - 14) + 4 · 3<sup>k</sup>

I will say that’s as far as I got because I have tried simplifying this multiple ways and I cannot even get it *close* to what it should look like. I’m starting to think I’ve made a mistake elsewhere. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using J.G.'s hint and then you can check your answer with the one below.

$P_k = 2 · 3^{k+1} - 14$

Therefore

$P_{k+1} = (2·3^{k+1} - 14)+4.3^{k+1}$

Add the $2·3^{k+1}$ and $4·3^{k+1}$ to get $6·3^{k+1}$

Then

$P_{k+1} = 6·3^{k+1} - 14=2·3^{k+2} - 14$

and you have the correct result.

Comment: I guess what I don’t understand what’s going on between the second and last step, can you add more context as to what’s going on there?

Comment: Is this the step you mean:-   $6·3^{k+1}=2·3·3^{k+1} = 2·3^{k+2}$

Comment: No, I get that i guess, I just don’t get how you go from the part with the substition to the final answer. I’ve been working on this all day and I just can’t seem to get it

Comment: Would you mind editing your answer to be a little more comprehensive on the steps?

Comment: Never-mind. I figured it out

Answer (score 0):

You should have added $4\cdot 3^{k+1}$. It'll work now.

Comment: Can you explain a little more? I’m still having trouble even with fixing that

Comment: @HelanaBrock Judging by your last comment on the accepted answer you came to understand this issue as I slept, but for what it's worth the problem was you'd added $P_k+P_{k-1}$, rather than $P_{k+1}-P_k$, to the value of $P_k$ assumed in the inductive step when you tried to verify $P_{k+1}$ has the value that step needs.